# is there any way to know if my app installed form app store?

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I have an app I want to publish on the SharePoint app store, on the same time I need to sell it direct to may private customer as a package.

I need to know form the app is it a app store vision or my private version. because I want to show them the support contact.

the easiest solution is create to versions, but this will be headache for updates and mintanance.

is there any way to know if my app installed form app store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you check the license information? If the app was installed from the store, it would have an associated license. If it was installed manually through the app catalog, it wouldn't.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164035.aspx#SP15Implementlicense_bk_implement